# multer removes the body from the incomming request

Tags: node.js, angular, express, multipartform-data, multer

I send an http post request from a simple Angular app in a form of `FormData` which is set the content type to `multipart/form-data`, the back-end receives the incoming request and parses it using [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)

after multer parses the request I always find that `req.body` is null

here is a [minimal reproduction](https://github.com/its-dibo/issue-multer)

### steps to reproduce

- install the dependencies `npm install`
- run the backend part `npm start` from the backend dir
- run the frontend part `npm start` from the frontend dir
- open your browser on `localhost:4200`, it will send an HTTP request directly to the backend without filling any form, and the received response is displayed on the same page.

the problem here is that it displays `{body:null,..}` where it should be `{body: {content: "test"}}`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is on the frontend with the [`toFormData`](https://github.com/its-dibo/issue-multer/blob/d541d63c39907b3366fdca148eb45d91f709d0ec/frontend/src/app/app.component.ts#L29) method, which constructs incorrect `formData`, which is why it's not parsed/empty on the server.

Two ways to fix it:

1. change `payload` to an object, instead of an array:

```
payload = { content: 'test' };
```

2. To use `payload` as an array, you need to loop an array and then loop object keys.

Try replacing it with this:

```
export function toFormData(data: any): FormData {
  let formData = new FormData();
  for (let obj of data) {
    for (let key in obj) {
      let element = obj[key];
      formData.append(key, element);
    }
  }

  return formData;
}
```